# How to join records from a group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I don't know if the title is as descriptive as I wanted but I'll try to explain with real examples of what I want.

In my table 'Details' I have

```
   Date   |   ProductId   |   Total   
-------------------------------------
17/05/20  |     16788     |    62
--------------------------------------
19/05/20  |     3789      |    15
```

So I want the result be something like that:

```
17/05/20 - 16788 - 62
17/05/20 - 3789  - NULL (or 0) 
19/05/20 - 16788 - NULL (or 0)
19/05/20 - 3789  - 15
```

I started doing RIGHT JOIN with a GROUP BY of the Dates, but didn't work. 
I run out of ideas, can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your details table, will you add more data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the rows with a `cross join` and then bring in the values using `left join`:

```
SELECT d.date,
       p.productid,
       t.total
FROM   (
           SELECT DISTINCT DATE
           FROM   details
       ) d
       CROSS JOIN (
                SELECT DISTINCT productid
                FROM   details
            ) p
       LEFT JOIN details t
            ON  t.date = d.date
            AND t.productid = p.productid
ORDER BY
       d.date,
       p.productid DESC;
```